# A class is repeated on other classes with react-spa-prerender

Tags: html, css, reactjs, single-page-application, prerender

I use **React SPA Prerender** to optimize SEO, and i got this problem :

I have a class called `HomeTitleContainer`, specifically used for the `Home.jsx` file, which is the home page.

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Link from '../immutable/nav/Link';
import './Home.css';

const Home = () => {
  
    return (
        <>
            <Container className="HomeTitleContainer">
                Ma Thématique
            </Container>
            <Container className="TableOfContentsLink">
                <p><Link link={'/cours'} internalLink={true} >- Des cours de mathématiques sur de nombreux sujets</Link></p>
                <p><Link link={'/bds-de-jpp'} internalLink={true} >- Des BDs de Jean-Petit</Link></p>   
                <p><Link link={'/jeux'} internalLink={true} >- Des petits jeux pour s'améliorer</Link></p>            
            </Container>
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Here is the corresponding css file, `Home.css` :

```
.HomeTitleContainer {
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    /* background-color: var(--front-color); */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--front-color), grey);    
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: var(--links-color);
    font-size: large;
    padding: 30px;
    width: calc(var(--window-width) * 3 / 4);
    box-shadow: 20px 20px 5px 5px var(--navbar-color);
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

@media (min-width : 450px) {
    .HomeTitleContainer {
        width: calc(var(--window-width) * 1 / 2);
        top: 50px;
    }
}
```

This `HomeTitleContainer` class is not present anywhere else.
But when i generate some html files according to my `.rsp.json` file, this class is present in all other generated html files.

To illustrate it, an example with the courses page...

All the pages have a table of content, so I use this file, `GenericTableOfContents.jsx` :

```
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Link from '../immutable/nav/Link';

const GenericTableOfContents = ( {items, prefix, title} ) => {

    return (
        <>
            <p className="MainTitle">{title}</p>
            <Row>
                {
                    items.map(item => (
                        <Container key={item.id} className="TableOfContents">
                            <Col xs={12} md={12}>
                                <div key={item.id} className="TableOfContentsLink" >
                                    <Link link={`/${prefix}/${item.relativePath}`} internalLink={true} >
                                        <div>{item.title}</div>
                                    </Link>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </Container>
                    ))
                }
            </Row>
        </>
    )

}

export default GenericTableOfContents;
```

You can see that the `MainTitle` and the `TableOfContents` classes should be one after the other.
But in `cours.html`, this sample is present :

```
<p class="MainTitle">Tous les cours</p>
<div class="HomeTitleContainer container">
<div class="TableOfContents container"> ...
```

Eventhough it shouldn't have to be there, a div with the `HomeTitleContainer` class has been added.

Here is the `.rsp.json` :

```
{
    "port": 3000,
    "buildDirectory": "./build",
    "routes": [
        "/",
        "/cours",
        "/bds-de-jpp",
        "/jeux",
        "/liens"
    ]
}
```

Here is the routes file (`AppRoutes.jsx`):

```
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './components/home/Home';
import CoursesTableOfContents from './components/courses/CoursesTableOfContents';
import ChaptersTableOfContents from './components/courses/ChaptersTableOfContents';
import GenericChapter from './components/courses/GenericChapter';
import PdfTableOfContents from './components/pdf-viewer/PdfTableOfContents';
import PDFViewerPage from './components/pdf-viewer/PDFViewerPage';
import GamesTableOfContents from './components/games/GamesTableOfContents';
import Links from './components/links/Links';
import VCard from './components/contact/VCard';
import Error from './components/immutable/Error';

const AppRoutes = ( {courseItems, pdfItems, gameItems} ) => {

    return  <Routes>
                {
                    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ?
                        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                            :   <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                }
                <Route path="/cours" element={<CoursesTableOfContents courseItems={courseItems} />} />
                {courseItems.map(courseItem => {
                    return  <Route 
                                key={courseItem.id}
                                path={`/cours/${courseItem.relativePath}`}
                                element={<ChaptersTableOfContents courseItem={courseItem} />} />
                
                })}
                {courseItems.map(courseItem => (
                    courseItem.chapters.map(chapter => {
                        return  <Route 
                                    key={chapter.id}
                                    path={`/cours/${courseItem.relativePath}/${chapter.relativePath}`}
                                    element={<GenericChapter chapter={chapter} courseItem={courseItem} />} />
                    })
                ))}
                <Route path="/bds-de-jpp" element={<PdfTableOfContents pdfItems={pdfItems} />} />
                {pdfItems.map(pdfItem => (
                    <Route 
                        key={pdfItem.id}
                        path={`/bds-de-jpp/${pdfItem.relativePath}`}
                        element={<PDFViewerPage pdfItem={pdfItem} />} />
                ))}
                <Route path="/jeux" element={<GamesTableOfContents gameItems={gameItems} />} />
                {gameItems.map(gameItem => (
                    <Route 
                        key={gameItem.id}
                        path={`/jeux/${gameItem.relativePath}`}
                        element={gameItem.component} />
                ))}
                <Route path="/liens" element={<Links />} />
                <Route path="/contact" element={<VCard />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Error />} status={404} />
            </Routes>
}

export default AppRoutes;
```

Added in App.js :

```
    var courseItems = coursesResourceBuilder();
    var pdfItems = pdfResourceBuilder();
    var gameItems = gamesResourceBuilder();
    <div className="App" >     

            <div className={`${theme} ${font} CopyBook`}>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Header courseItems = {courseItems} pdfItems ={pdfItems} gameItems={gameItems} /> 
                        <Container className = {` RelativeContainer ${playMode ? "PlayMode" : ''}  ${isLoading ? "Blur" : ''} `} >                           
                            <AppRoutes courseItems={courseItems} pdfItems={pdfItems} gameItems={gameItems} />
                        </Container> 
                    <Footer /> 
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div> 

    </div>
```

And here is the url of the website :

https://ma-thematique.netlify.app

https://ma-thematique.netlify.app/cours

Can somebody can help me please ?

Comment: Can you post the code for `<Container />` compoennt?

Comment: It is a Bootstrap component.

Comment: Can you post your `React Router Dom` routes?

Comment: @Dimitar I posted it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `Styled Components` to avoid `CSS` from applying globally:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const HomeTitleContainer = styled.span`
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, var(--front-color), grey);
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: var(--links-color);
  font-size: large;
  padding: 30px;
  width: calc(var(--window-width) * 3 / 4);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 5px 5px var(--navbar-color);
  margin-bottom: 100px;

  @media (min-width: 450px) {
    width: calc(var(--window-width) * 1 / 2);
    top: 50px;
  }
`;

export default HomeTitleContainer;
```

Then inside of your `Home` component:

```
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Link from '../immutable/nav/Link';
import './Home.css';
import HomeTitleContainer from "./HomeTitleContainer";
import React, {Fragment} from "react";

const Home = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Container>
      <HomeTitleContainer>
        Ma Thématique
      </HomeTitleContainer>
    </Container>

    <Container className="TableOfContentsLink">
      <p><Link link={'/cours'} internalLink={true} >- Des cours de mathématiques sur de nombreux sujets</Link></p>
      <p><Link link={'/bds-de-jpp'} internalLink={true} >- Des BDs de Jean-Petit</Link></p>   
      <p><Link link={'/jeux'} internalLink={true} >- Des petits jeux pour s'améliorer</Link></p>            
    </Container>
  </Fragment>
)

export default Home
```

Can you try this and let us know what the result is?

There are two things which attempt to solve the problem here:

1. Using `empty tag` instead of a `Fragment` - A Fragment allow you to group children without adding extra nodes to the DOM and make your component structure and rendering logic more clear and concise. Empty tags, on the other hand, do not provide these benefits and can lead to additional, unnecessary DOM nodes. This can cause some unusual behavior, especially in older versions of react.
2. Using a `CSS` file instead of `styled-components`. If you use a `CSS` file, the CSS will apply globally and if you are not careful enough, you can easily render a div with a class name that has defined properties in one of your `CSS` files.

Comment: Thank you very much ! That fixed the problem.

Can you develop in a few words your solution ?

Comment: Only add the Fragment component fixed the problem...

Comment: Moreover, only <></> (the reduced Fragment syntax) worked as well